# Accessing data with nested for loops from Nasa Neo API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, loops, for-loop, nested

Very new to coding and I feel like I bit off more than I can chew for my final project. I'm trying to access the data from Nasa's Neo API. The data I need is nested. The code I wrote gets the "Object" in the array but then I can't access the data for the "Object"

```
BASE_URL = "https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed/today?detailed=true&api_key=DEMO_KEY"

//Read the data
d3.json(BASE_URL).get(function(data) {
  console.log(data)

var d = data["near_earth_objects"]
console.log(d)
var today = [];
for (today in d["2020-01-08"]) {
  console.log(today)
}
```

[Console.log info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDXaK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there! The relevant line is `for (today in d["2020-01-08"]) {`. In a `for` loop declaration, `in` loops over the *keys* of an object. For an array, that will be the indices, and that's why it is printing out "0, 1, 2, 3...". Writing `for(today of d["2020-01-08"]){` (note the `of`) will loop over the items in the array, which is probably what you want.